# Apparently Non-Sense 404 Cross-Browser Error

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am encountering an all-browser bug via the WP-FB-AutoConnect wordpress plugin. After successful login (confirmed via logs and session testing) the callback_function.submit() to the form is resulting in a 404 error. However, when I refresh the page, the file does in fact exist. It is as if there is some sort of encoding error in the action attribute of the  element, however, I have tried all obvious fixes, from urlencode() to htmlentities().

Since I cannot provide an example because it is in a protected development environment, please allow me to describe how the plugin works. I have a strong feeling this has nothing to do with the particular plugin, and instead is a result of something I am simply not familiar with.

1. User clicks Facebook Login.
   [image]
2. Facebook login prompt appears as expected, and user clicks 'allow'
3. Session is started. Confirmed in logs, and confirmed by visiting website to check session.
4. However, when the form is submitted via callback [document.callback_function.submit() contained in function provided to Facebook API] the resulting page is a 'Link appears to be broken [chrome]'.
   [image]
5. The file exists. This is confirmed by refreshing the page that the browser is saying does not exist.
   [image]

Some notes:

1. Permissions are correct. The page loads on refresh. The file exists.
2. This bug appears in Webkit and Moz, I didn't bother with IE because that's an entirely different set of headaches.
3. The link is correct and none of the characters in the URL appear to be encoded incorrectly.
4. Again, zero errors in any logs.

Please note: I am having a hard time describing this bug because it's very inconspicuous. I have never encountered anything like this in my 13 years of web development.

It is my hope that there is someone out there who has experienced something like this and has any input on the matter. I am really hoping that this is just a moment of humility for me. After hours and hours of debugging an invisible bug, and resisting coming here due to my lack of ability to describe the issue, I have no other choice. I cannot find any occurrence of this bug, either Facebook Login specific bugs, or generally within Javascript, browser issues or server-side issues through such avenues as Google or Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you try to submit the form while the Chrome console is open? In particular, open the Network tab and click the "dot" button at the bottom ("Preserve log upon navigation"). My guess is that there's some weird redirect going on. With the Network tab on, you might be able to see what's happening.

Comment: Inspecting, will follow up shortly.

Comment: So get this, I wake up this morning ... give it a try .... VIOLA! It works. The gremlins in my system laugh at my demise, and at the 8 hours I wasted yesterday. Certainly a moment of humility for me.

Comment: ... And a second try, it doesn't work. There is nothing significant in console.

Comment: So yesterday I cleared history and cache, as part of my normal debugging process, and it didn't help. But I considered also clearing my sessions and cookies. It appears that if I clear cookies, the script works once. If I attempt to use it any subsequent times, the behavior described in this post occurs. Could this be something with the HEADERS and x-cache?

Comment: This problem is still evident and still driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the script, from the error your browser sent, it seems as if there's an error in the script itself, which causes it to fail. PHP cannot parse errors if they happen before the site is done loading.